TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type dict which has no callable sqrt method
I am stuck with an error:
psi_out_norm.append(np.sqrt(sorted_probs))
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type dict which has no callable sqrt method

Not sure how to resolve this error. Below is the code i am working on:
import numpy as np
num_qubits = 2
sorted_probs = {'00': 0.1826131640519985, '01': 0.3015290853531944, '10': 0.3171301575715357, '11': 0.1987275930232714}
all_possible_keys = [format(i, f'0{num_qubits}b') for i in range(2**num_qubits)]

psi_out_norm = []
for key in all_possible_keys:  
    count = sorted_probs.get(key, 0) # use 0 if the key is missing
    psi_out_norm.append(np.sqrt(sorted_probs))

It would be great help if someone can help me in this error.

You have not specified what np is. I'm assuming it is numpy. Is that right?

Yes, np means numpy.

You are trying to run np.sqrt on a dictionary. This is what causes the TypeError. You can replace sorted_probs with count:
import numpy as np
num_qubits = 2
sorted_probs = {'00': 0.1826131640519985, '01': 0.3015290853531944, '10': 0.3171301575715357, '11': 0.1987275930232714}
all_possible_keys = [format(i, f'0{num_qubits}b') for i in range(2**num_qubits)]

psi_out_norm = []
for key in all_possible_keys:  
    count = sorted_probs.get(key, 0) # use 0 is the key is missing
    psi_out_norm.append(np.sqrt(count))


np.sqrt() takes in an array_like object. You have passed in a dictionary which seemingly does not satisfy this requirement :)
If you are wanting to get the square root of every value within sorted_probs, you could do something like:
import numpy as np

sorted_probs = {'00': 0.1826131640519985, '01': 0.3015290853531944, '10': 0.3171301575715357, '11': 0.1987275930232714}
psi_out_norm = np.sqrt([prob for _, prob in sorted_probs.items()])
print(psi_out_norm)

Which produces: [0.42733262 0.54911664 0.56314311 0.44578873]
